# if I initialize a char array to zero/{0} do I have to null terminate?

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, c-strings, null-terminated

Say for instance I declare a char array with all values set to zero in the following fashion:

```
char array[4] = {0};
```

If I assign it values, for instance:

```
array[0] = 'A';
array[1] = 'B';
array[2] = 'C';
```

Do I need to null terminate the array like so?:

```
array[3] = '\0';
```

or does the operation `char array[4] = {0}` null terminate previous to any assignment?

Comment: The array is completely filled with 0 bytes. Null terminating is not different from that. But there will not be another element added for the null byte.

Comment: So in other words {0} null terminates the string?

Comment: Be aware that `char array[4] = {'A'};` does not fill the whole array with `A`s, but only the first element. The rest however is filled with 0s.

Comment: As with all variable initializations, members that do not have an initializer are zero-filled. if you provide `{0}` there will be 1 byte from your initializer list and the rest will be filled with zeros. If you use that array for a string with up to 3 character, it is null-terminated. If you use it for different purpose, it still contains 0 bytes, but the term "null termination" has no meaning there.

Comment: Conceptually, this writes a nul terminator a second time. Practically, assuming things are in scope, a compiler should be able to recognize the superfluous write and get rid of it. On a personal note, I think the explicitness is preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do I need to null terminate the array like so?

No. `'\0'` is just a fancy way of writing `0`. It's a way to write self-documenting code referring to the null terminator specifically, out of tradition. (It's actually just a zero written as an octal escape sequence, of all things.)

Since you already set all items to `0`, there is no need for an extra `\0`.

Comment: Also note that `char array[4] = "";` would also set all items to zero.

Comment: Out of curiosity would `char *array; memset(&array[0], 0, sizeof(array));` be the equivalent of `char array[4] = {0}`?

Comment: @Lundin huh?? `array` points nowhere and `sizeof(array)` is the size of the pointer.

Comment: @asd23553 no, but `char array[4]; memset(&array[0], 0, sizeof(array))` would be.

Comment: Yeah well obviously you have to allocate room for the array. I didn't even react on that part. It should be `array[4]` indeed or you can neither memset nor sizeof.

Comment: *"`char array[4] = "";` would also set all items to zero"*, is it in the specs, or compiler specific?

Comment: @e2-e4 Yes it is guaranteed by the rule for partially initialized "aggregates" (structs or arrays). "...all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."

Answer (score 4):

This declaration

```
char array[4] = {0};
```

is equivalent to

```
char array[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 19 The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each
> initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any
> previously listed initializer for the same subobject;151) **all
> subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized
> implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration**.

and

> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
> explicitly, its value is indeterminate. **If an object that has static
> or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:**
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
> unsigned) zero;
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively)
> according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
> ...

So the element array[3] contains 0. Until it will be overwritten the array contains a string.

An alternative initialization by zeroes of a character array is the following

```
char array[4] = "";
```

or the following

```
char array[4] = { "" };
```

or even the following

```
char array[] = { [3] = '\0' };
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char array[] = { [3] = '\0' };
    
    array[0] = 'A';     //  the array contains a string
    
    printf( "%s\n", array );
    
    array[1] = 'B';     //  the array contains a string
    
    printf( "%s\n", array );
    
    array[2] = 'C';     //  the array contains a string
    
    printf( "%s\n", array );
    
    array[3] = 'D';     //  the array does not contain a string
    
    printf( "%.*s\n", ( int )sizeof( array ), array );
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
A
AB
ABC
ABCD
```